# Can you use a LED driver (WS2801) for a 4-20mA control loop

Tags: led, current, plc, industrial

I am trying to make a 4-20mA control loop on a home made sensor that will connect to a PLC. I was using Texas Instruments XTR111AIDGQR, but it is too expensive, costing $1.72. so want to try switching it out with WS2801, an LED driver that costs $0.13.

The LED driver documentation says it has a wide output current range up to 150mA, which can be adjustable to the LED current. I limited the current to 20mA using a 30ohm resistor as shown in the diagram below. I will use the TWI (Two Wire Interface) to "Dim" the 20mA current.

[image: sensor schematic]

Will this application work? Am I not considering something that will make this not work?

WS2801 datasheet:
[image: WS2801 datasheet]

Comment: Depends. Are any other devices on the line allowed to sink the signal to ground to indicate a fault? What range of compliance voltage do you need to provide?

Comment: No other devices are on the line. The sensor will use software to limit the 4-20mA current from going under 4mA. The sensor is independently powered.

Comment: And at what compliance voltage?

Comment: It is the same as VCC. VCC is -0.3 to 6V.

Comment: How? Show schematic.

Comment: @bradosia If it isn't clear to you, an LED driver (implemented as a controllable current sink) isn't a good answer to winny. I believe winny wants to know about the sensor's voltage compliance requirements. Not the LED driver specs.

Comment: @jonk Thanks for the clarification. It's a home-made sensor board I'm making that is powered off 5V. I can try uploading the schematic, but it will take a little time to put it on a single image.

Comment: @bradosia Okay. That's good information, already. So it only needs 5 V of compliance voltage.

Comment: I'm fishing for how OP is going to match the compliance voltage between driver and receiver. There is a magic word for it but I want OP to figure it out for him/herself to learn something from the experience.

Comment: the transmitter and receiver are powered separately, but have a common ground. Does the voltage matter for the 4-20mA line?

Comment: Yes! Fill out the minimum character count.... Aaaand post!

Comment: @winny Sorry, what does that mean?

Comment: There is a 15 character minimum for each post so any Yes/No answer needs to be filled in with something more to make it at least 15 characters.

Answer (score 1):

The XTR111AIDGQR provides a DC current.
  The WS2801  provides a PWM signal, not DC.

You have pin RFB pulled high, that is not going to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjh8L4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Typical 4 - 20 mA sensor connection to PLC analog input.*

Most PLC analog inputs are dual-purpose. The support 0 - 10 V input or, by addition of a 250 Ω shunt resistor, convert 20 mA to give 5 V on the input. The resolution is halved when using current rather than voltage but this is seldom a problem.

In the spirit of the comments to your question I will prompt you to work out:

- How will you source current for the loop using a chip designed to sink current from the LEDs?
- What voltage will be on R1 at 20 mA?
- What voltage is required at V+ to get that voltage on R1?